# Magento 2 checkout sidebar

Tags: magento2

[Need to link this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvXoE.png)

Site
http://www.vecocraft-ebikes.de/
Magento 2 sidebar on checkout. issue is Right side bar show number of product added thumbnails and name i want thumbnails and name of the product to be linked to actual product.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would turn on "Template Path Hints" to locate the template file where the image is loaded.

Then check if you can access the cart item and the products URL so that you can then insert a link right there on the image.

Comment: All data load using HTML file
Magento_Checkout/template/summary/item/details.html

And here data comes form js file
module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js

i try to change both file but not success.if you have any idea then please share.

Thanks